# Flask session variable not allowing assignment

Tags: python, session, web, flask

I've been building a web application for the past month, and things have been going surprisingly smoothly for how new I am to all of this.  That is, until yesterday, when I did an AJAX overhaul on a page to provide users with live feedback of a server-side process.  Now when I boot up the application, I get an error on my first line of code (which has produced no problems up to this point) where I check the session object to see if an operation is active.

I am getting the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'session' referenced before assignment
```

when I try the code:

```
if 'active_op' not in session:
    print 'bizbaz'
```

I would have thought that I was doing something wrong with this code if it hadn't worked seemlessly before.  I've reverted my code to what I had before the AJAX update, and I'm still getting this error, even though it worked yesterday with the same code.  Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.  As I said, I'm still kind of new to web application development and sessions, in particular.  Apparently my understanding of sessions and flask's use of them is a bit off, because I'm completely stumped as to why this has suddenly stopped working.  Let me know if there's anything I can do to clarify my issue; I'm stuck until I get this figured out.  Thanks!

EDIT:
I had this code which was trying to assign a dictionary to the session variable.

```
session = {'foo':'bar'}
```

Comment: You're going to need to show more code. If for example session is a module level variable but you're assigning to it anywhere in the function, you'll get this error if you attempt to read it before the assignment.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman. That was the problem.  I did a search and replace to clean up some of my code, and I missed a spot where session was assigned to a dict.

Comment: I edited your question to include this information about "session assigned to a dict". I will also edit the answer from Sergey to mention this which should complete the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you import session before you use it

```
from flask import session
```

**EDIT**

The main problem was that you were assigning a dictionary to the 'session' variable which you should not do.

```
# Incorrect
session = {'foo':'bar'}
```

Instead, it should be

```
session['foo'] = 'bar'
```

Comment: I did. I'm working on a fix right now; something I missed earlier, I'll let you know if it solves this.

Comment: No luck.  Really not sure what's causing this.  I pulled some code from a few days ago, and that is working with the session in the same place, as expected.

Comment: I am correct in assuming that session exists once it's imported, though, right? I don't need to initialize it or anything before I can run a check like this?  It's really throwing me that it worked before, and I can't seem to find any discernible difference that would make it behave like a 'local variable'.

Comment: It's at 666 LOC now; maybe that's the problem :p

Comment: May not need to: If I were to have inadvertently assigned a value to 'session' at a later point in the code, would python flag this like it has?  There was some pretty cavalier search and replacing as part of this AJAX update, and I think I missed a little spot where the key value was dropped off of session and it is just assigned as: session = {'foo': 'bar'}

Comment: It still may work as expected, if you import it from flask. And session is not a dict it is SecureCookieSession object [link](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py#L109)

Comment: AHA!  That was it; I'm a goon.  Appreciate the help, though.  Getting on here and talking to a human being was helpful.  If you wanna post something about checking the code for an accidental assignment to 'session', I can accept that as the answer ;D @Sergey Bargamon

Comment: I edited the answer to include the actual cause and resolution as suggested by Sergey